# PyCharm 2019 doesn't see Jupyter package if I use system interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I used PyCharm 2018 on Windows / MacOS with Python 3.6 and all works normally. Now I have a problem on both platform with PyCharm 2019 (I tried different versions of that).

If I using System interpreter I get Jupyter package is not installed message when want to run any Jupyter notebook cell. It only works if use virtual environment or Conda.
Any ideas?

Of course I tried reinstall Jupyter, and PyCharm listed these packages as installed.

Comment: are you able to use the Jupyter package if you open an interactive shell using the System interpreter?

Comment: How can I check this?